# Libusb Isochronous Audio Transfer

Tags: android, c++, audio, libusb

I'm currently developing an Android app using `libusb` at C++ side via JNI. I've been doing a really deep research about USB Audio Class and libusb. I've read almost every documentation and seen every bit of example codes but none of them is satisfying and I still have some questions.

So I have several questions unfortunately but I will ask one per thread :)

First, I want to support most major USB sound cards so I cannot hardcode the `Sampling Frequency` or `Packet Size`. What must be the way to calculate Packet Size? I do it in this way:

> If 1 sample is 16 bits and if the sampling freq is 48000 then I must
>   have 96000 bytes per second. It will be good to buffer 10ms of samples
>   so I have to buffer 960 bytes. As my Endpoints wMaxPacketSize is 100,
>   I have to have 10 packets with size of 96 bytes in a single transfer.

Is this a good way to calculate the packet size?

Thanks in advance :)